# Use Open API Cdiscount to find products

Tags: node.js, axios

I would like to be able to display different Cdiscount products from a search on my site.
I use Open API Cdiscount, however I get the impression that it doesn't always work.
On Postman, it only works in 'POST' and with Axios I don't know whether to put the parameters in a body or something else?

I'm a little lost, there is no documentation ...

Some examples, on Postman in 'POST' with my parameters, I have many results, in 'GET', the request is executed endlessly.

Axios side, I think I did my request well:

```
        axios.get('https://api.cdiscount.com/OpenApi/json/Search', {
        params: {
            ApiKey: 'TOKEN',
            SearchRequest: {
                Keyword: 'harry potter',
                Pagination: {
                    ItemsPerPage: 5,
                    PageNumber: 0
                },
                Filters: {
                    Price: {},
                    Navigation: 'books',
                    IncludeMarketPlace: true
                }
            }
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: CDiscount OpenApi returns empty results since two weeks for me.